# How to format an Integer to a four-zero-left string?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, integer, string-formatting

I'm trying to do something like it in java (Eclipse Indigo):

```
input - 16 (integer);
Output - "0016" ;

input - 201 (integer);
Output - "0201" ;

intput - 1716 (integer);
Output - "1716" ;
```

In VB.net I could use:

```
dim num as integer
dim str as string

str = Format(num, "0000")
```

How can I do the same in java? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also go for the `String#format()` as answered by *mre* but you could also do:

```
new DecimalFormat("0000").format(number);
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for further details.

Answer (score 10):

[`final String s = String.format("%04d", yourNumber)`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Note that there is a locale-sensitive version of this method as well.

Comment: See [the Formatter JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for the full formatting rules.